# Ionic splash screen not visible

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, splash-screen

I have created an ionic application ,even the default ionic splash screen is not visible. I have added png files for both icon and the splash screen and issued the command '`ionic resources`', even though it does not show up the splash screen.

[image]

[image]

Even though the icons and splash screen are not shown.

Every time a start a new project this type of screen is shown even if i manually add appropriate icon and splash image.

[image]

Code of config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.attendencenew299323" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>attendenceNew</name>
  <description>
        An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.
    </description>
  <author email="you@example.com" href="http://example.com/">
      Your Name Here
    </author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true"/>
  </feature>
  <platform name="android">
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
  </platform>
</widget>
```

Comment: Have you also removed the platform and added it again? These images should also be visible in your platform/android/res/resources directory

Comment: Check the related issue: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/1608

Answer (score 0):

That is the cordova defualt splash screen, and I guess you used this command to bild your app

```
cordova build android
```

but if yo want get your ionic icon and splash screens you need to build using ionic.

Do the following :

1 - remove your platform :

```
cordova platform remove android
```

2 - add your platform

```
ionic platform add android
```

3- run this command to create your splash screen and icon

```
ionic resources
```

4 - build your app

```
 ionic build android
```